import lines are not readable
// SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {IAccount} from "lib/account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/IAccount.sol";
import {PackedUserOperation} from "lib/account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/PackedUserOperation.sol";
import {Ownable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import {MessageHashUtils} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MessageHashUtils.sol";
import {ECDSA} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol;
import {SIG_VALIDATION_FAILED, SIG_VALIDATION_SUCCESS} from "lib/account-abstraction/contracts/core/Helpers.sol";
import {IEntryPoint} from "lib/account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/IEntryPoint.sol";

contract MinimalAccount is IAccount , Ownable {
    address private immutable i_entryPoint;

    constructor(address entryPoint) Ownable(msg.sender) {
        i_entryPoint = entryPoint;
    }
    // A signature is valid , if it's the MininalAccount owner
     function validateUserOp( PackedUserOperation calldata userOp, bytes32 userOpHash, uint256 missingAccountFunds  external returns (uint256 validationData){
       validationData =  _validateSignature(userOp , userOpHash);
       // _validateNonce()
       _payPrefund(missingAccountFunds);
    }

    // EIP-191 version of the signed hash
    function _validateSignature(PackedUserOperation calldata userOp , bytes32 userOpHash) internal view returns(uint256 validationData) {
        bytes32 ethSignedMessageHash = MessageHashUtils.toEthSignedMessageHash(userOpHash);
        address signer = ECDSA.recover(ethSignedMessageHash , userOp.signature); // who did the signature
        if(signer != owner()) {
                return SIG_VALIDATION_FAILED;
                }
            return SIG_VALIDATION_SUCCESS;
     }
    
    function _payPrefund(uint256 missingAccountFunds) internal {
        if(missingAccountFunds != 0) {
            (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: missingAccountFunds, gas: type(uint256).max}("");
            (success);
    }
}

The error is:
Error: 
failed to resolve file: "/home/cromewar/foundry-f24/account-abstraction/lib/openzeppelin-contracts/access/Ownable.sol": No such file or directory (os error 2); check configured remappings
        --> /home/cromewar/foundry-f24/account-abstraction/src/ethereum/MinimalAccount.sol
        @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol

I have successfully installed all the dependencies for openzeppelin and account abstraction using forge install. Also, I have done remapping in .gitmodules file but still it can't read the file from the import.


As, you've defined the remappings in your .gitmodules file, so you've to import the dependencies using the root of the path (excluding the lib/ portion) that you've defined in your .gitmodules file, like:
import {IAccount} from "account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/IAccount.sol";
import {PackedUserOperation} from "account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/PackedUserOperation.sol";
import {Ownable} from "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import {MessageHashUtils} from "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/cryptography/MessageHashUtils.sol";
import {ECDSA} from "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol;
import {SIG_VALIDATION_FAILED, SIG_VALIDATION_SUCCESS} from "account-abstraction/contracts/core/Helpers.sol";
import {IEntryPoint} from "account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/IEntryPoint.sol";

NOTE: If you want to import the account-abstraction and openzeppelin-contracts using syntax like @account-abstraction and @openzeppelin respectively, then you've to define the corresponding remappings in your foundry.toml file too, like:
remappings = [
    "@account-abstraction = lib/account-abstraction"
    "@openzeppelin = lib/openzeppelin-contracts"
]

Then, the imports will be like:
import {IAccount} from "@account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/IAccount.sol";
import {PackedUserOperation} from "@account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/PackedUserOperation.sol";
import {Ownable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import {MessageHashUtils} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MessageHashUtils.sol";
import {ECDSA} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol;
import {SIG_VALIDATION_FAILED, SIG_VALIDATION_SUCCESS} from "@account-abstraction/contracts/core/Helpers.sol";
import {IEntryPoint} from "@account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/IEntryPoint.sol";


I was making a syntax error. Thank you for your reply
